# only google.com returns "Sorry, host not found."

Tags: google-chrome, dns, hosts

I can do an nslookup on google.com and get an IP. I can connect to the IP in my browser window and do searches. but google.com and chrome bar searches will give me an error "Sorry, host not found"

I can find remarkably little about this online. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Are you physically located in a country that could be blocking it (like China)?

Comment: Do other google variants work? For example google.co.uk?

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know if you are on Windows or Linux - I'm assuming it's Windows.

1. **Check your hosts file** (normally `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`). If you have any entries there redirecting google.com, you will need to remove them. This would be a sign of malware infection, by the way.
2. Check and disable any **toolbars and add-ons** that look suspicious in Chrome.

It is common for adwares to redirect google.com to their own fake (and ad-bloated) search engines. This could explain the behavior you're getting - but it's just one possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your browser cache.  I frequently come across issues on the system I support where the browser cache gets corrupted and it appears that there is no connectivity to 1 site.    (You can also use another browser).

Answer (score 1):

If it is not the hosts file or an adware on your computer as pointed out by @pgr, it could possibly be your DNS server. If you're in a country which blocks Google's DNS name, your ought to try changing your DNS server to Google's Public DNS Server. It might be a bit slower than your local DNS servers but will ensure you almost 100% uptime and resolves to the correct servers. You can change your DNS Servers via your network adapter.

1. Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
2. Right-click your active network adapter and click properties
3. Select the Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) item and click the
   properties button.
4. Click the Use the following DNS server addresses: radio button and
   type in 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for the preferred and alternate
   DNSservers, respectively.
5. Press OK. Click Close. Test out http://www.google.com